# NoneType object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I'm working through Automate the Boring Stuff and in part II I have an issue with some code as what is returned is an AttributeError, even though I copied exactly what is written in the book:

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\(\d\d\d\))(\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My Phone number is (415) 555-4242.')
mo.group(1)
mo.group(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space in `'(415) 555-4242'` - the regex only matches phone numbers without spaces. You can change the regex to `r'(\(\d\d\d\))\s*(\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)'` - `\s*` matches any amount of whitespace or nothing.